# kibana 4 discover table in dashboard

Tags: kibana-4

How can I add a visualize "widget" discover table in my dashboard. To emulate the feel of kibana 3.

Currently in kibana 4 you have the first tab "discover" that provides that functionality. But the dashboard(s) and discover are not linked.

Thank you

Comment: while not an exact duplicate of this question, the answer is the same.

Comment: Thanks it is a work around but good enough :) thanks